# Recovering folder deleted sudenly / recovering ssd raid 0+1 hp

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, hp, raid

**Server HP G9 - DL 360**

**Ram :**256 GB Ram

**SSD :** 4 SSD 500Gig Samsung EVO (All Samsung ssd hard is configured to Raid 0+1)
https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/MZ-76E500B/EU/

**Sas :**1 TB Sas HP

**OS**: Ubuntu 20.04 TLS minimal

**Virtualization** : VMware ESXI

In vmware I had 2 data store, it means 2 partioton that show me,
on off them is the HP 1TB sas and the second datastore or partiton belong to All 4 ssd disk of samsung that was crated in raid 0+1

In ssd hard (raid 0+1) I crated a Linux Machin and installed the ubuntu 20.04 tls minimal and in it I installed the cybepanel for web hosting and Litespeed for webserver.

Last night, my server was crashed and show me the error 500 and, in my logs, I saw there was problem to renew the SSL, and found that because my disk space is full.

with `df -h` I found the `/dev/sda2` is 100 percent full and with `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 -x` I found this this path `/usr/local/lsws/logs` is responsible for the disk space
In this image you can see what was that.

[image]

I though is better idea to move a single log to another folder for downloading and opening with code editor because sudo nano command couldn't show the log file.
So I used the command for moving the file like this :

```
# Sudo su – 
# rm -r /logs/lswchefile2022-04-06-logs    /home/mysite/
```

And I got error that folder is not empty
After that, my site was not open and I cheek and saw there is no file in my folder `/home/mysite/`

**For now, is there any way to recover deleted file over Linux or by hp provisioning tools?**

I need emergency help and any help would be appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu? What does SSD hard mean?

Comment: I was going to edit this question to make it more readable but there is so many confusing statements I can not do it. Like this one. <I had 2 data store, on off them was the first one > There are several others as well. Can you maybe edit this and have it be much more clear?

Comment: This is not improved the strange statements are still there and now you say you got 256 Gigs of RAM?

Comment: Hello , Are you familiayr with Servers and Hardwares?

Comment: There is no way back from a `rm` other than a backup or the use of data recovery tools. If you have no backup then you would be normally be advised to take the disk offline and clone it. Then you would try to recover data from the clone. The name of the lost path suggests there could be a lot of individual files involved so this would not be quick and easy.